# Memory allocated using cudaMalloc() is accessable by host or not?

Tags: cuda, nvidia

In the book CUDA By Example on page no 26 it written that:

> You can pass pointers allocated with cudaMalloc() to functions that
>   execute on the host.
>
> You cannot use pointers allocated with cudaMalloc() to read or write
>   memory from code that executes on the host.

To demonstrate the first concept I am writing the code here:

```
main()
{
int * ad, N;

cudaMalloc((void **)&ad, Sizeof(int) *N);

GPUFunction<<<...>>>(ad);
Hostfunction(ad);

}


Hostfunction(int * AD)

{

int c ;

c=AD[N-1];

printf("%d", c);

}


  __global__ void GPUFunction(int *AD)

{

AD[threadIdx.x]= threadidx.x;
}
```

Is this what the point# 1 above explains? If so it in contradiction to point# 2 above, as you can see the host function is reading memory ad. So where is my understanding going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The two points are not in contradiction.

The first point simply means that you can pass the `AD` pointer to the `HostFunction` exactly as you are doing, but this does not mean that you can direcly access device memory by

```
c=AD[N-1];
```

as the second point is telling you.

What you can do is to use the pointer to perform, for example, other `cudaMemcpy` operations or to pass that pointer to a `__global__` function.

So, a possible `HostFunction` could be

```
__global__ void GPUFunction(int *AD)
{
    AD[threadIdx.x]= threadidx.x;
}

Hostfunction(int * AD)
{
    GPUFunction<<<...,...>>>(AD);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I *cannot* see that the host function is reading memory `ad`.  You've certainly written some code that attempts to do that, but it's invalid code and  it will seg fault.

Since the code you've provided here is not complete or compilable, it doesn't demonstrate anything.

Here's a compilable example pretty close to what you have typed in, which demonstrates that your `Hostfunction` will not work correctly when passed `ad`:

```
$ cat t251.cu
#include <stdio.h>

  __global__ void GPUFunction(int *AD)

{

AD[threadIdx.x]= threadIdx.x;
}

void Hostfunction(int * AD, int N)

{

int c ;

printf("preparing to read ad in host code\n");
c=AD[N-1];

printf("%d", c);

}

int main()
{
int * ad, N;
N = 1;
cudaMalloc((void **)&ad, sizeof(int) *N);

GPUFunction<<<1,1>>>(ad);
Hostfunction(ad, N);

}


$ nvcc -arch=sm_20 -o t251 t251.cu
$ ./t251
preparing to read ad in host code
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
$
```